# Psycopg2: Can a result set be changed during iteration?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have code where I'd like to iterate over all rows in a table. I cannot store all the rows in memory so I have to use an iterator:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM some_table;")
for row in cursor:  # cursor itersize is small
    do_something(row)
```

Is it possible for another transaction to modify some_table while iterating? And more importantly, will it change the results of the iteration? Note that this table can have thousands of rows, each with multiple megabytes of data.

Comment: You might want to check https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, someone else will be able to change the table (unless you have taken locks you haven't shown us or something).  No, you won't be able to see those changes, you will continue to read the original data.

If you are using the serializable isolation level, then if you read data that was since changed (and that change was committed) you will get a serialization error when you commit.